# Google Sheets script - If a value in cell 1 hits a new high or low, I need to update cell 2 w/ new value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On my Google Spreadsheet, named 'Portfolio', I have 3 rows:

1. Row 1 contains formulas for current stock price, such as
       `=GOOGLEFINANCE("VTI")`, for about a dozen stocks going down the row. For this example this is in cell A2.
2. Row 2, cell A3, will contain data for when the price in A2 reaches a lower amount than A3
3. Row 3, cell A4, will contain data for when the price in A2 reaches a higher amount than A4

[image]

The challenge I'm having, and I feel it's simple but for some reason am racking my brain on it, is I need the value in cells A3 & A4 to stick once it's hit. So if the price of VTI hits a new low during trading hours, I want that low to update to cell A3 and to not change unless it hits a new low later that day or next month. Same goes for the high in A4.

Here's what I have so far in the script editor:

```
function storeValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Portfolio');
  var A2cell = sheet.getRange('A2').getValues();
  var A3cell = sheet.getRange('A3').getValues();
  var A4cell = sheet.getRange('A4').getValues();

  if (A2cell<=A3cell) 
  {
    A3cell.setValue('A2');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this a little bit.  I thought I'd share it with you and see how quickly you can shoot some holes through it.

The **v1** parameter is the Cell reference to the cell you want to watch.

The **name** parameter is a name given to that value that will be used in the property service to store the last lowest value so that you can use the formula in more than one cell without interacting with other instances.

One of the issues I had was that I don't know if it's possible to determine where the formula has been located or where the cell that your monitoring is located if I could then I could use the cell A1 notation as the name.

```
function WATCHFORNEWLOWS(v1,name){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if(!ps.getProperty(name))ps.setProperty(name,v1);
  if(v1<ps.getProperty(name)) {
    ps.setProperty(name,v1);
    return v1;
  }else{
    return parseInt(ps.getProperty(name));
  }
}
```

I hope this helps but I have significant doubts.

Comment: I would think that I would need to create a new script for every ticker in row 1 instead of creating one script to rule them all. I feel the latter would be cumbersome as you suggested. I'll try and implement this using the cells in my example. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Entered this but I think I'm missing something to tell the script where to apply the stored value once it's lower. Or, I have no idea because I'm definitely not a coder by trade.

function watchForNewLows(A2,vtiLow){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEST');
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if(!ps.getProperty(vtiLow))ps.setProperty(vtiLow,A2);
  if(A2<ps.getProperty(vtiLow)) {
    ps.setProperty(vtiLow,A2);
    return A2;
  }else{
    return ps.getProperty(vtiLow);
  }
};

Comment: I used it like this: `=WATCHFORNEWLOWS(A1,"A1")`

Comment: You don't have to create a new script you just have to change the name for every cell so that your creating a different property key.

Comment: It seems to work until I go back to the script, tweak something, and save it. After I save it, it the high/low reset to whatever is in cell A1. 

I added a second function for highs, named WATCHFORNEWHIGHS, to the same script. Then I went back and created two more functions for two more tickers after doing so noticed that if I save the script, it resets the cells to A1, B1, etc.

Comment: I guess it's not going to work.  Sorry I couldn't do better.

Comment: Damn close though. Thanks for your help. I'll see what else I can tinker with.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by using the GOOGLEFINANCE formulas.

If you read the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) for it, the second parameter is what value you want to fetch.

In your case, you want your cells to be:

- `=GOOGLEFINANCE('VTI','high')`
- `=GOOGLEFINANCE('VTI','low')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, ZektorH. I did know about that however it doesn't have high and low APIs for something like, say, BTCUSD, which is one of the investments I'm creating a tracking database for. Most likely, I was going to probably just go with this option and manually track BTC's highs/lows which isn't the end of the world. I just prefer a program do it for me. 

Thanks again for reaching out!